# PHP Unlink , go back up folders

Tags: php

I am having trouble unlinking images in PHP

The image is located here

```
http://localhost:8888/REVLIVEGIT/wp-content/uploads/dropzone/1420280588-example_023.jpg
```

The delete php file is located here

```
http://localhost:8888/REVLIVEGIT/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/inc/delete.php
```

My delete.php code is this

```
<?php
//$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$upload_dir = '/REVLIVEGIT/wp-content/uploads/dropzone';

$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].  $upload_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
//$targetPath = 'wp-cotent/uploads/dropzone';  //4

$pictures = $_POST['data'];
foreach ($pictures as $x) {
    if(isset($x))
    {
        //echo $x;
        echo $targetPath;
        unlink($targetPath.$x);
    }
}
?>
```

I can find the file using absolute path in HTPP, but you can't unlink over HTTP for good reason

I can't navigate back through the folders by doing this

```
../../../uploads/dropzone
```

as the target path just comes out as the above, it doesn't traverse the directories

I have no problems with my upload.php file (below for reference)

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = '../../../uploads/dropzone';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
    $mainFile = $targetPath.time().'-'. $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $name = time().'-'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$mainFile); //6
    echo $name; 
}
?>
```

Can some assist me in finding the way to my file when unlinking

Comment: What does `$_POST['data']` contains? A filename with a front-slash in front of it?

Comment: An array of file names - just the file names no slashes

Comment: in the case above post $_POST['data'] would contain 1420280588-example_023.jpg

Comment: @DarkBee The execution flag -x is not needed to delete files. I can delete files without problems without the execution flag. Just the user(group) must have permission to read and write.

Comment: Always use absolute paths, never relative paths.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois through it's the write flag that the directory needs as well. Sorry :)

Comment: read and write is set on directory, you can't use absolute paths when unlinking. Error i'm getting is cannot find file which I assume means my path is wrong, just can't get the correct path to the file

Comment: Of course you can use absolute paths when unlinking. That's what I always do.

Comment: Yeah got confused with http path etc, agreed to your point above

Comment: What's the full path and filename unlink gets passed? Is the path correct?